# Java package folders with a dot in the name

Tags: java, classpath

Is it by spec that, given a `MyClass.java` file containing

```
package com.mycorp.foo;

public class MyClass {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, world!");
  }
}
```

in the following path (note the dot in the folder name):

```
./com/mycorp.foo/MyClass.java
```

the following works fine:

```
$ javac com/mycorp.foo/MyClass.java
```

producing `./com/mycorp.foo/MyClass.class` while this doesn't work:

```
$ java com.mycorp.foo.MyClass 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mycorp/foo/MyClass
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycorp.foo.MyClass
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Comment: `javac` is *very* "open" to where the input lies. It doesn't enforce the rules of correct source file placing. You could theoretically have all your Java source files (from different packages) in the same directory. It's not a good idea, but you could. `java` however *does* require the rules to be followed. So no: the directory name should be `com/mycorp/foo`.

Comment: Right.  The directory structure must be reworked, or else replace the troublesome "." with "_" or such.  Java expects to find an object in package x.y.z in path x/y/z, and I can think of no way to get around that.

Comment: @JoachimSauer You should write your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The packaging structure mentioned at the top of the class file **has less to do with compilation** and more to do with **Runtime class loading**.

1. You can put any packagename and compile it. e.g. following java class compiles

   ```
   package com.sa.test.me.yes.no;

    public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println("Hello");
    }

     }
   ```

It compiles **even if you don't put inside a folder structure** same as package declaration. You can test it by not putting in any folder (e.g `java Test.java`)

2 . Packages organization is more important while class loading. The **classloader** will always search for the class into the **folder based on package structure**. So when you are trying to run your program, the classloader tries to search for the class file in a folder as per the package structure.

Comment: It might compile or give a compile error depending on the Java compiler used. See [Java Language Specification 7.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6).

Answer (score 1):

The [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html) points to the fact the source tree does not have to match the object files tree. `javac` lets anything go for that very reason, but `java` will require the directory structure to follow the standard of having one subdirectory per element of the dot-separated package name.