# Compiler error when the folder contains dot (.)

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project structure like :

```
src/main/java
   com
     company.project.utils
            MyClass.java
```

When I try to use the package :

```
package com.company.project.utils;
```

I got an error in Eclipse because it expects that the structure was :

```
src/main/java
   com
     company
         project
             utils
               MyClass.java
```

The problem is that I cant change the structure because there are lots of projects like this and depending of that.

If i compile this project in maven  it's ok , also my colleages don't have compiler errors in IntelliJ.

Is there a way to say Eclipse that the dots are part of name folder instead of a new folder  ??

Comment: have you tried using `/` or `\ ` (windows)? or escaping the dots like this: `\.`?

Comment: Is it a compiler error or a warning? Anyway, directories in source folders should NOT contain dots.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java package folders with a dot in the name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719306/java-package-folders-with-a-dot-in-the-name)

Comment: That's a restriction given by the _Java Language Specification_, see in [7.6 the example: `wet.sprocket.Toad` → `wet/sprocket/Toad.java`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6)

Comment: Your structure is not according to java conventions.  Just fix the technical debt now.

Comment: Also if this works in IntelliJ a bug report should be issued