# Folder name with dot not recognised as package in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, package, ide

I created a folder a.b.c in src directory and added a file Test.java, something like this

[image: Package Structure]

My Test.java looks like this

[image: Source File]

When I compile using `javac` it works, IntelliJ also works, but with Eclipse I get error

> The declared package "a.b.c" does not match the expected package

Any help would be great

Thanks!

Edit : Adding IntelliJ Structure

[image]

Comment: Each part must be a separate folder  - Folder ''a', with folder 'b' inside it, with folder 'c' inside b.

Comment: `a.b.c` is not a valid identifier. You can't use that as package name.

Comment: @greg-449, I agree, but Java doesn't complain neither IntelliJ.

Comment: That is as may be but Eclipse insists on this.

Comment: @ernest_k : If that's not valid , javac shouldn't compile it.

Comment: Can you show your IntelliJ project structure too?

Comment: See [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10719306/2670892) - it may compile but the class loader won't find the class at run time.

Comment: @ernest_k : Added IntelliJ structure .

Comment: It's not _supposed_ to work. It's a bug that it works in IntelliJ. Use `a/b/c`.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- : Even if it is a bug with intelliJ, `javac` works perfectly fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java package folders with a dot in the name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719306/java-package-folders-with-a-dot-in-the-name)

Comment: What is right and wrong is given by the Java language specification, not by (a specific version of) `javac` or an IDE. According to the Java language specification, this can, but must not, be an error. IMHO at least an IDE should not accept this folder structure, because there is no guarantee that it works with all Java tools of all versions (including upcoming versions of `javac`).

Comment: On a side note, for the java.compiler API JavaFileManager, the characters '.' and '/' are interchangeable "for convenience". I could imagine javac may provides similar behavior for convenience. If it is not in any specification, then other compilers don't have to do the same though.